# Drawing a circle in C++, but drawing a diamond instead

Tags: c++, drawing

I am working on a coding project that has us drawing various shapes using asterisks. I've so far drawn an X, a rectangle, and the upper and lower parts of a square. The final project has us drawing a circle, and the same method I've been using for the 4 previous projects - creating a kind of grid of sorts using nested for and if else loops, and specifying where to draw a " " or a "*" is falling short. Here is my code:

```
int main() { 

int rad; // int for radius


cout << "We are creating a circle made of asterisks. Please input the radius: " << endl;
cin >> rad;

int i; 
int t;


for(i = 1 ; i <= (rad * 2) + 1; i++) 
{
    for(t = 1; t <= (rad * 2) + 1 ; t++) 
    {
        if((i == 1 && t == rad + 1) /*|| (i  == (rad * 2) && t == rad + 1) || (i == rad/2 && t == rad/2)*/) 
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        else if (i >= 2 && i <= rad && t == (rad+1) - (i-1))
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        else if (i >= 2 && i <= rad && t == (rad+1) + (i-1))
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        else if (i >= rad && t == (i - rad))
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        else if (i >= rad && t == (rad * 2) + 2 - (i - rad))
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        else 
        {   
            cout << " ";
        }
    }
    cout<< endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

The output of the above? A perfect diamond:

```
    We are creating a circle made of asterisks. Please input the radius: 5

     *     
    * *    
   *   *   
  *     *  
 *       * 
*         *
 *       * 
  *     *  
   *   *   
    * *    
     *
```

Obviously my method isn't working. I've tried adjusting my parameters to increase the spacing of my asterisks, creating a kind of a rough approximation of a circle, but it just doesn't look right. I can't help think there has to be an elegant, superior way of doing this. Maybe a more mathematical approach that uses the radius. Any suggestions or tips?

Comment: How can you draw a circle without using geometry?

Comment: What makes the points of a circle... a circle, is this: **(x-cx)^2+(y-cy)^2=r^2**. You have an unjustified amount of conditions.

Comment: You can check this out: [Visit this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356723/how-to-draw-a-circle-with-asterisk-function-in-ruby)

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++. The question is about what is the correct math for drawing a circle. The problem has nothing to do with C++ syntax, or rules. The math is just wrong. You need to use either sin()/cos(), or a crafty application of sqrt().

Comment: Filled circle is easier than just circle. Since you can use "bool b = x\*x+y\*y < r*r;" and you end up with nice filled circle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more mathematical approach that uses the radius  to draw a circle.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int pth (int x,int y)  {
    return sqrt (pow(x,2)+pow(y,2));
 }

int main ( )  {

    int c=0;
    int r=10;

    const int width=r;
    const int length=r*1.5;

    for (int y=width;y >= -width;y-=2)  {
        for (int x=-length;x <= length;x++)  {

            if ((int) pth(x,y)==r) cout << "*";
            else cout << " ";

         }
         cout << "\n";
     }
     cin.get();

return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some hints on how to draw a circle:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/circle_generation_algorithm.htm
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm